# AS3 Events Not Behaving In FireFox and Safari

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I apologise for a slightly fuzzy question but there are no other developers in my office and I need some help from somewhere. If you can even suggest a vague topic for me to look into it would be great as I have been banging my head against this all day with zero progress.

So, I have built a little image display widget (Flash CS6, FlashPlayer 10.3, AS3).
It is simply a container clip into which I load a a stack of images (wrapped in a custom class), one on top of the other but offset a little so that the side of each is visible to be clicked.

Each of the images listens for `MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER` and becomes the active image when this happens, I also have a listener attached to the `stage` of their container clip that listens for `Event.MOUSE_LEAVE` and updates the display when the user is not actively engaging with the Flash area.

Everything works fine when I run within Flash and also when I test in Chrome but in FF and Safari when I mouse out of the Flash area, as well as the expected `MOUSE_LEAVE`, a `ROLL_OVER` is also registered by the very bottom image in the stack. This means that whenever you mouse out in the affected browsers the bottom image always becomes active rather than the last one you actually rolled over.

Any thoughts, even vague possibilities, would be great because I am stumped. This is either some really tiny detail of Flash event propagation that I'm not getting or some stupid mistake that I've over thought into a mountain :)

Right now I will take what-ifs, maybes, legends, riddles, anything!

Sorry again for the rather rambling explanation.
Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: So are you saying a roll over event is dispatched even though you actually didn't roll over the last item in the stack? Is the "last item" under the mouse at all? Maybe code or an annotated screen shot might be useful to show what is happening.

Comment: Exactly that. I have now changed it so that only a small part of each of the images is listening for roll_over but the event still fires (on the lowest item in the stack) even though the mouse is over 100px away! This only happens when the cursor moves in and out of the flash area so I guess it could be browser related rather than Flash.